# Can't load XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml

Since some time I need to load data from XML and XML files can be in different format.
I don't know which format I'm loading, but I have bytes array of loading XML. So, I tried to read some rows for determine the version of file, because all file is too big:

```
string sFileHeaderPart = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(uplFile.FileBytes, 0, 176);
if (sFileHeaderPart.Contains("DATA_CATALOG"))
{
    // version 1
}
if (sFileHeaderPart.Contains("FormatVersion"))
{
   // version 2
}
```

The value of sFileHeaderPart for "version 2" I got like these:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataList xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <FormatVersion>2.0</FormatVersion>
```

With "version 1" all ok.
But with "version 2" is a problem.
I have tried this code:

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(sFileHeaderPart); // <-- got an exception here
```

and this code:

```
System.Xml.XmlTextReader r = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(sFileHeaderPart));
while (r.Read()) // <-- got an exception here
{
    if (r.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element && r.Name == "FormatVersion")
    Console.WriteLine(r.ReadOuterXml());
}
r.Close();
```

So, please, help me to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and add in the text of the exception / error you're receiving.

Comment: The tiny bit of XML you show (in the part after _"The value of sFileHeaderPart for "version 2" I got like these"_) is not well-formed.  The `<DataList>` element is never closed

Comment: Why are you only reading the first 176 bytes of `uplFile.FileBytes`?

Comment: Don't say "<-- got an exception here" without telling us anything about the exception. What's the Message, StackTrace, InnerException, etc?

Comment: I got an exception with message: "Invalid data at root level., Line 1, position 1." So, it don;t like this line: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: Well, `<DataList>` is your root object, and, if it is what you show, it's not well-formed

Comment: It looks like you're trying to just load `sFileHeaderPart` 9the first 176 bytes) and not the whole XML string. If the information that you want to switch off of is part of the XML document, I would just read in and parse the whole XML document in either case and then just switch your logic based on the presence of specific _elements_.

Comment: The exception is telling you that your XML is invalid.  So, fix the XML structure, or don't attempt to load it as XML.

Comment: The issue seems to be solved using the code in your 1st code block that contains the `if` statement-although it looks like you should have used `if-else` instead of 2 `if` statements. According to the information you've given, there are 2 options: `Version 1` and `Version 2`. You stated: "With "version 1" all ok". Since version 2 only ever has a value of `2.0`, there's no need to read the value of `FormatVersion`, because the value can only ever be `2.0`. If you're only using the 1st 176 characters, it's trival to use `String.Substring` along with `IndexOf` to get the value of `FormatVersion`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your comments. So, I fixed the problem by removing the first row and adding a closing tag. Now sFileHeaderPart looks like:

````
<DataList xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <FormatVersion>2.0</FormatVersion>
</DataList >```
````

Comment: You can self-accept answers.